# Determining matrix which represents Linear Transformation

Tags: linear-algebra

Let F : E
3 → E
3 be one of the two possible orthogonal rotations of angle 5π/6 around
the line of equation 2x + y + 5z = 0 = 4x − y + 10z. 
I.Determine the matrix representing F
II.Determine if such a rotation is a direct isometry.
I am struggling to see relation between ''orthogonal rotation'' and linear transformation as i have never encountered a question like this.And i am not sure what is meant by "direct isometry"

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**

We can proceed as follow

- find the normalized direction vector $\vec v$ for the given line
- complete a basis by two orthonormal vectors $\vec u$ and $\vec w$ orthogonal to $\vec v$
- in the basis $\{\vec u,\vec w,\vec v\}$ the rotation matrix is given by

$$R=\begin{bmatrix}\cos \theta &-\sin \theta &0\\\sin \theta &\cos \theta &0\\0 &0 &1\end{bmatrix}$$

- then change basis from $\{\vec u,\vec w,\vec v\}$ to the canonical

Recall that if the orientation stays the same we say that the
isometry is *direct*, if the orientation changes we say that the isometry is *opposite*.

Comment: 1.Direction vector: (2,1,5)x(4,-1,10)=(15,0,-6)
2.Orthogonal complements: u=(0,1,0) and w=(2/5,0,1)
3.So our basis {u,w,v}={(0,1,0) (2/5,0,1) (15,0,-6)}
I don't understand how to use our basis {u,w,v} in rotation matrix provided.

Comment: @TuranNasibli Matrix $R$ represents the rotation in the given basis (with $\theta =5\pi/6$ or $=-5\pi/6). To find the rotation matrix in the standard basis we nedd to change basis.

Comment: So we need to express our Matrix R in canonical basis,but the process of finding rotation matrix for our basis isn't clear to me.Could you help with that?

Comment: In the given basis $u=(1,0,0)$ and $Ru=(\cos \theta, \sin \theta, 0)$ similarity for $w=(0,1,0)$ while $v=(0,0,1)$ is fix since $Rv=v$.

Comment: @amd Yes you are right! I'v fixed that. Thanks